# Map Spark DataFrame Colunm value with JavaRdd<Row >

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I created two DataFrames from Sqlcontext.

```
            DataFrame edge_dataframe = SharedSC.getEdgeDataFrame("EDGE_RDD", -1234, sc.getSparkContext());
            DataFrame vertex_dataframe = SharedSC.getVertexDataFrame("VERTEX_RDD", -1234, sc.getSparkContext());
```

- vertexDataFrame

### vertexColumn

saman

kumara

malith

- edgeDataFrame

### |src  | dest

sman  | malith

kumara |   malith

like that.
But For construct a Graph from that data.i wanted to add Long unique id field to verted table and change the edge table using that ids.

first i add unique long id to vertex table.

```
            JavaRDD<Row> ff = vertex_dataframe.javaRDD().zipWithIndex().map(new SerialiFunJRdd<Tuple2<Row, Long>, Row>() {
            public Row call(Tuple2<Row, Long> rowLongTuple2) throws Exception {
                return RowFactory.create(rowLongTuple2._1().getString(0), rowLongTuple2._2());
            }
        });
```

now i want to change my edge DataFrame src and dest columns to Long ids.how can i do that.Please help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using List.it may not be the best approach.but it solved my problem.

First i mapped "JavaRdd Row  to  JavaRDD Tuple2

```
JavaRDD<Tuple2<java.lang.Long,String>> vertex_javardd = ff.map(new SerializableFunction<Row, Tuple2<java.lang.Long, String>>() {
public Tuple2<java.lang.Long, String> call(Row row) throws Exception {return new Tuple2<java.lang.Long,String(row.getLong(1),row.getString(0));}});
```

then converted it to a List

```
List<Tuple2<Long,String>> vartexlist= vertex_javardd.collect();
```

now i can iterate through the List and get mapped id for the selected edge attribute.